# Any idea, belief etc. regarding the hatred of men

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, word-difference

What do you call thoughts, beliefs which are indicative of hate men? The words that I can make-up are as below, although dictionaries do not include any if them and it was why I needed to ask you:

> 1) misandric 
>   2) misandrist 
>   3) misandristic

**Example:** Her................thoughts of men are really embarrassing.

I think none of my made-up words would work in this sense, so please let me know what word is used in this specific sense?

Comment: Are you looking for the opposite of 'misogynistic"? Or rather, the same, but applied for men?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [**Misandry**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misandry):

> **Misandry** is the **hatred** of, **contempt** for, or **prejudice** **against men or boys**."Misandrous" or "misandrist" can be used as adjectival forms of the word. Misandry manifests itself in numerous ways, including sexual discrimination, denigration of men, violence against men, and sexual objectification of men.

You can find in Wiktionary [**the family of words**](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=misandr*&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&ns0=1) around it, with their explanations.